# Mounting Wubi part from another Linux installation

Tags: mount, wubi

hope someone can help.
I need to access 11.04 ubuntu files residing on a second hard drive (dual boot XP/Ubuntu) from  a 10.04 hard drive installation. The 11.04 system co-exists with XP on the second drive. This drive is HPFS/NTFS. My 10.04 installation mounts and displays the contents of the XP installation and all files but the 11.04 system is nowhere to be seen. How can I see and access the Ubuntu partition, please?

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean Wubi as saying "co-exists". As an example **I assume your XP installed on sda1**. Change sda1 according to you partition name. On 10.04 apply those:

If not mount sda1 first:

```
sudo mkdir /media/xp
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/xp
```

Then mount Wubi part:

```
sudo mkdir /media/wubi
sudo mount -o loop /media/xp/ubuntu/disks/root.disk /media/wubi
```

You can find your 11.04 on /media/wubi directory.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply heartsmagic. I'm fairly new to linux but I guess the HPFS/NTFS disk does contain a 'wubi' install. fisk -l gives:  Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1       19079   153247744   83  Linux
/dev/sda2           19079       19453     2999297    5  Extended
/dev/sda5           19079       19453     2999296   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Comment: All goes okay until: sudo mount -o loop /media/xp/ubuntu/disks/root.disk /media/wubi where it fails with: no such file or directory

Comment: Ok, after mounting xp part look for ubuntu or Ubuntu directory. There must be a disks directory and inside it a root.disk part. If it is Ubuntu change the last mount command with this capital name.

Comment: Thanks again heartsmagic. Apologies. Seems I was probing the wrong disk!! It does contain an XP installation, but no wubi so I was never going to find or see it. Must have mislabelled the disk : (( Now have correct disk which in fact turns out to be pure Ubuntu 11.04 and 10.04 sees everything just fine. Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: So, it is not a Wubi installation and there is a seperate 11.04?

Comment: Yes...I felt sure it was a wubi installation because I remember installing 10.04 that way some time back. At some point I must have reinstalled Ubuntu and upgraded to 11.04 on another disk leaving XP to reside alone on the original hd. There is no ubuntu folder in the XP install. Confusion reigns supreme hereabouts...